# Change dropdown selected text different than actual option text

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

There's dropdown with multiple options. First option is selected one, so you can see this options text at first look at dropdown (collapsed state).

Is there any way to display only part of selected options text when dropdown in collapsed state, but when expanded, then show this corresponding option with full text?

To better understand what i want, i have made drawing: http://goo.gl/BSwOi

Comment: Your drawing doesn't work anymore. Next time, upload it into the question as an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fix the width, for example. I used this HTML:

```
<select style="width: 40px">
    <option value="Volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="Saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="Opel">Opel</option>
    <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MzZxG/

Comment: Thought about that, but what if option texts consists of lets say 3 words (various lengths) & you need to display only the first word of option text as collapsed dropdowns visible text? And if there are multiple dropdowns like that? - that would mean i should provide different width for each of them. what if option values are dynamic?

Comment: @Gaccho Then you'd have to use jQuery to set the width by finding the longest first word in an option, then multiplying the number of letters by say 5px. That would do it dynamically for all.

Comment: So: we determine the longest first word of the options text in one specific dropdown. Let's say its 9. we set the dropdown width calculated from that. So what happens when in this dropdown selected options first word is 5 in length? - it will display the first word + 4 following characters, correct? Anyway - Isn't there any other way to do this without changing the width of dropdown?

Comment: You'd call your recalculation on dropdown change. There isn't another way to do it unfortunately, what you want is a fixed width dropdown, but that fixed width is variable dependent upon content, so the process outlined above is your only real option :)

Comment: I see. Thanks. I was thinking - would it be worth to use lists formatted as dropdown instead of actual dropdown? Like here - http://goo.gl/mLL2N .

Comment: @Gaccho No problems, they look pretty good. Will give you a lot more control yeah.

Comment: @Gaccho If this helped you, please click the green tick and mark it as the correct answer.